# Web Scraping con Python

Tags: python, pandas, web, scraping, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de hacer un scraping de tablas de una pagina y despues de la quinta fila empieza a arrojar NaN, lo hice en Pandas porque despues quiero usar esa informacion en excel, y en Beautiful soup, pero llego al mismo resultado.
Mi codigo es:

```
import pandas as pd
pagina = 'http://prestadores.pami.org.ar/result.php?c=6-2-1-1&beneficio=150596476607&parent=00&vm=2'
df = pd.read_html (pagina)[2]
df[0:10]
```

El codigo con BS es mas complejo, pero da el mismo resultado (puse una pagina diferente a la de Pandas):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime

page = requests.get(
    'http://prestadores.pami.org.ar/result.php?c=6-2-1-1&beneficio=150495628501&parent=00&vm=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table1 = soup.find('div', {'id': 'contenedor'})


df = pd.read_html(str(table1))
print(df[2].columns)
print(df[2][df[2].columns[0:4]])
```

Si alguien me puede brindar alguna sugerencia les agradezco mucho.

Comment: Revisa que en esa fila no tenga caracteres diferentes a los que ya le programaste en el código porque ten en cuenta que el sigue el proceso tal cual como se lo indicas pero no se si tal vez en la fila 5 se añade algún parámetro nuevo o diferente se va ha dañar, revisa eso y si es el caso prográmalo para que cuando encuentre algo así haga algo que ya le hallas programado.

Comment: Gracias, me estuve fijando y no veo nada